# iphone - navigation controller - move to first view from last view without traversing all intermediate views

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i'm working on iphone app which will show 4 buttons in first view. on click of a button, it will load a new view with navigation controller. this navigation controller view allows to travel upto 11 sub views. in 11th sub view, i've a reset button. on click of reset button, i've to go back to navigation controllers first view without traversing all the 11 views? is it possible to achieve it? if yes how? if no, what can be the solution?

Comment: if your first view is the RootView then you can use michael's answer and if its other than root view you can use my answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use `[self.navigationController popToViewController:objFirstViewController animated:YES]` in the 11th view when you want to pop directly to the first view.

And if you are sure that you have to move to the first view and it is a rootviewcontroller then you can directly use
`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Happy Coding..